# Error access the properties of a query - AngularJS + Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have problems with basic Firebase query, it is with the rest of the application have no problem to bring data and work with them. And even with Firebase Authentication.

However, with these queries, when I try to access its properties returns an undefined me. Although it is clearly defined.

Does anyone see the error? Thanks.

Versions with whom I work are:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.8",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "angular-bootstrap": "^2.1.0",
    "angularfire": "^2.0.2",
    "firebase": "^3.3.2",
    "angular-animate": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-route": "^1.5.8",
    "textAngular": "^1.5.11",
    "angular-socialshare": "angularjs-socialshare#^2.3.1",
    "angular-timeago": "^0.4.3"
  }
```

This is the view:

```
<div ng-controller="blogpostCtrl">
{{post}}
{{post.Title}}
</div>
```

This is the content of firebase:

```
{
  "blog" : {
    "posts" : {
      "-KT9vxYoCkly93GqTSY7" : {
        "CreationDate" : 1475504757165,
        "Post" : "<p>esto es una prueba de post</p>",
        "Title" : "esto es una prueba",
        "Url" : "esto_es_una_prueba",
        "isPublished" : true
      },
      "-KTA-f-BDAzC-4T4a50K" : {
        "CreationDate" : 1475505991860,
        "Post" : "<p>dsf sdf sdfs fd</p>",
        "Title" : "o1i21o3i",
        "Url" : "o1i21o3i",
        "isPublished" : true
      },
      "-KTA-ggQSQLnDr4eQtfi" : {
        "CreationDate" : 1475505998783,
        "Post" : "<p>ds sdf sdf</p>",
        "Title" : "4 45654456 2546345562535",
        "Url" : "4_45654456_2546345562535",
        "isPublished" : true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the controller:

```
app.controller("blogpostCtrl", function($scope, $location, $routeParams, $firebaseArray) {
  var ref = firebase.database().ref("blog/posts");

  $scope.post = $firebaseArray(ref.orderByChild("Url").equalTo($routeParams.uri));

  console.log($scope.post)
  console.log($scope.post.Title) //<------------ undefined

  firebase.database().ref("blog/posts").orderByChild("Url").equalTo($routeParams.uri).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val())
    console.log(snapshot.val().Title) //<------------ undefined
  });
  firebase.database().ref("blog/posts").on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val())
    console.log(snapshot.val().Title) //<------------ undefined
  });
});
```

And this is the console output:

```
[]0: Object$$added: ()$$error: ()$$getKey: ()$$moved: ()$$notify: ()$$process: ()$$removed: ()$$updated: ()$add: ()$destroy: ()$getRecord: ()$indexFor: ()$keyAt: ()$loaded: ()$ref: ()$remove: ()$save: ()$watch: ()length: 1__proto__: Array[0]
ctrl.js:163 undefined
ctrl.js:170 Object {-KT9vxYoCkly93GqTSY7: Object, -KTA-f-BDAzC-4T4a50K: Object, -KTA-ggQSQLnDr4eQtfi: Object}-KT9vxYoCkly93GqTSY7: Object-KTA-f-BDAzC-4T4a50K: Object-KTA-ggQSQLnDr4eQtfi: Object__proto__: Object
ctrl.js:171 undefined
ctrl.js:166 Object {-KTA-ggQSQLnDr4eQtfi: Object}-KTA-ggQSQLnDr4eQtfi: ObjectCreationDate: 1475505998783Post: "<p>ds sdf sdf</p>"Title: "4 45654456 2546345562535"Url: "4_45654456_2546345562535"isPublished: true__proto__: Object__proto__: Object
ctrl.js:167 undefined
```

Comment: ofcourse it is undefined. `Title` is a property of another object

Comment: Yes, I have seen the error, at least in queries of the snapshot. But when working with $ scope.post = $ firebaseArray (ref.orderByChild ("URL") equalTo ($ routeParams.uri).); I have the problem.

Besides, I can not get the key of some data, which are those that I consult. If I had the key, I do not make query with a field inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.Title` is a property of the child object so this is why you are getting undefined. If you need that Title you must include the object key as well, for example:

```
console.log($scope.post.blog.posts['-KT9vxYoCkly93GqTSY7'].Title)
```

Check this fiddle based on your json response
http://jsfiddle.net/b2pfLp26/

About your `$filterArray` you have to wait before getting the console printed so you have to make use of `.then`.

```
var array = $firebaseArray(ref.orderByChild("Url").equalTo($routeParams.uri));

array.$loaded().then(function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. You're right for the last two queries with snapshot. However, for this query it does not work.                                                    $scope.post = $firebaseArray(ref.orderByChild("Url").equalTo($routeParams.uri));

Although the array generated has a value of 0, I can not access or as scope.post.Title $ or $ scope.post [0] .title.

Comment: @Epifanio your last two queries they make use of `then` which is the correct way, change your first query as well

Comment: @Epifanio updated my answer with an example of how `firebaseArray` is used

Comment: Thanks again @Akis! The firebaseArray of angularfire, if I use it as you indicate, not get the title. console.log (response.Title); He thinks that is then called from the view as {{post.Title}}. One option that I can think of is to use ng-repeat = "post in onepost" and give the value of the query to "$scope.onepost". But I do not see a good solution.

Comment: @Epifanio do a `console.log(response.blog.posts['-KT9vxYoCkly93GqTSY7'].Title)` and YES ng-repeat is the correct way, you can see on the jsfiddle example that i gave in the answer